# Swift: Simple - how do I refer a button's name dynamically?

Tags: swift

I've been searching this goddam question for over an hour and it's so simple!

I have 9 images and I want to refer to any one of them in a function. They're all named "img1" "img2" etc. They're also linked to my code with IBOutlets.

```
Func changeImage(imgNumber: Int){

imageName = "img" + String(imgNumber)
self.imageName.image = UIImage( named: "smiley.jpg") }
```

Instead of the imageName variable I know I can just refer to the actual object by saying "self.img1.image" but that wouldn't allow me to dynamically alter any image with a function.

Please help!

Comment: You can put all of your images into an array and refer to them by array index.

Answer (score 0):

Put your image in an `Asset Catalog`.

(You can create one by New file... > iOS Resource > Asset Catalog).

In the asset catalog give your images name like image1, image2, image3 etc.

`UIImage(named: "image1")` will find images in the Asset Catalog.

The benefit of using `Asset Catalog` is that you can easily add images supporting the different screen resolutions there as well.

Optionally load them manually, and put them in an array and access by index if there is a logical order to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You should put them in to a collection (in viewDidLoad for example) that preserves the order, ie.

```
var images = [self.img1, self.img2, self.img3]
```

and use the index to access the specified button

```
images[idx].image = UIImage(named: "smiley.jpg")
```

If you need even more dynamic order, you could use tag for this and traverse the subviews to find the specified view. I wouldn't recommend this though, as it is a pain to debug.

You could use outlet collections but to my understanding they don't preserve the order. This would mean you'd have to find another way to sort the buttons (x-coordinate, y-coordinate or tagging).